# Which edition and version of Visual Studio 2019 am I using?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

**Background**

I am setting up a new laptop, and Visual Studio 2019 was already installed. I want to make sure I have the latest Enterprise version, not Community or Professional or an early version.

**Question**

Which edition of Visual Studio 2019 do I have?

**Things I've tried**

1. Taskbar icon > Visual Studio 2019 > Properties > Shortcut > Comment > Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 is the most detail I get.
2. Stack Overflow search above this question editor comes up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which edition and version of Visual Studio 2019 am I using?

**Solution**

Open Visual Studio > Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio > Read the version and edition!

The versions of .NET framework and other tools are also listed.

[image: Visual Studio > Help Menu > About Microsoft Visual Studio Menu item]

[image: About Microsoft Visual Studio Menu > Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4]